# Does PyQtGraph have an option for placing symbols on only some fraction of points, similar to Matplotlib's markevery keyword?

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

The following code snippet and plot shows how Matplotlib's `markevery` keyword can be convenient for placing markers on line without cluttering the plot by marking every point in a large dataset. Is there a similar feature in PyQtGraph, or do I just have to call plot twice to put symbols on a subset of the data?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 151)
y = x**2

pg.plot(x, y, symbol='o')

plt.plot(x, y, marker='o')
plt.plot(x, y+10, marker='o', markevery=10)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this keyword does not exist in pyqtgraph, you could simply use the following code instead:

```
pg.plot([j for i, j in enumerate(x) if i%10==0], [j for i, j in enumerate(y) if i%10==0], symbol='o')
```

where you could replace `i%10==0` with `i%z==0`, where `z` is equivalent to the `markevery` integer.

--or--

```
def pg_markevery(arr, markevery):
    return [j for i, j in enumerate(arr) if i%markevery==0]

pg.plot(pg_markevery(x, markevery=10), pg_markevery(y, markevery=10), symbol='o')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I suspect a keyword does not exist natively in pyqtgraph and I will have to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do for suppressing the line:

```py
pen = pg.mkPen(color=(0, 0, 0), width=0.001)
graph.plot(
       xvals,
       yvals,
       pen = pen,
       symbol = "o")
```

Where `graph` is an element of the class `PlotWidget`.

Setting the width to exactly 0 does not work, but setting it to a small number like 1e-3 will eliminate the line and only the symbols remain.